# Select 2 Wrapped component duplicated when loading options

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I've created a wrapped vue component in laravel in order to wrap jQuery select2 element.
Based [in this code](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html).

When the values in select.options change, the select element is duplicated. Like the following image.
[image]

The selection only works in the second select.

I don't know what is the problem, I add below the code I have made and the content of the options variable.

**`select2.vue`**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <select>
            <slot></slot>
        </select>
    </div>

</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: "select2",
        props: ['options', 'value'],
        mounted: function () {
            let vm = this
            $(this.$el)
                // init select2
                .select2({ data: this.options })
                .val(this.value)
                .trigger('change')
                // emit event on change.
                .on('change', function () {
                    vm.$emit('input', this.value)
                })
        },
        watch: {
            value: function (value) {
                // update value
                $(this.$el)
                    .val(value)
                    .trigger('change')
            },
            options: function (options) {
                // update options
                $(this.$el).empty().select2({ data: options })
            }
        },
        destroyed: function () {
            $(this.$el).off().select2('destroy')
        }

    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

**`blade` file call**

```
<select2 :options="select.options" v-model="select.value"></select2>
```

**`select.options` data**

```
          [
                {
                    "text": "Group 1",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "text": "Element 1"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 2,
                            "text": "Element 2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "text": "Group 2",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": 3,
                            "text": "Element 3"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 4,
                            "text": "Element 4"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried for a while to reproduce the problem you were having, without any success.

I noticed a couple of things that might help you:

`this.$el` refers to the `div` in your example, where as the [examples](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage) I've seen use `select`.

Try and avoid using the same names for properties and variables, as this makes it confusing `options: function (options) {`

I've included a snippet below in case it helps.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

Vue.component("select2", {
  template: "<select style='width: 100%'></select>",
  props: ['options', 'value'],
  mounted: function() {
    let vm = this
    $(this.$el)
      .select2({
        data: this.options
      })
      .val(this.value)
      .trigger('change')
      .on('change', function() {
        vm.$emit('input', this.value)
      })
  },
  watch: {
    value: function(value) {
      $(this.$el)
        .val(value)
        .trigger('change')
    },
    options: function(val) {
      $(this.$el).empty().select2({
        data: val
      })
    }
  },
  destroyed: function() {
    $(this.$el).off().select2('destroy')
  }
});


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => {
    return {
      selected: null,
      options: [{
          "text": "Group 1",
          "children": [{
              "id": 1,
              "text": "Element 1"
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "text": "Element 2"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "text": "Group 2",
          "children": [{
              "id": 3,
              "text": "Element 3"
            },
            {
              "id": 4,
              "text": "Element 4"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
  modifyOptions() {
  this.options = [{
          "text": "Group 1",
          "children": [{
              "id": 4,
              "text": "Element 1"
            },
            {
              "id": 6,
              "text": "Element 2"
            }
          ]
        }];
  }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <select2 :options="options" v-model="selected"></select2>
    <div>
    Selected: {{selected}}
    </div>
    <button type="button" @click="modifyOptions">Modify Options</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've found the problem, I was calling to select2.min.js in the scripts section of the blade template, show the call to select2() was duplicated. Thank you very much for your help.